# How do I call functions from 'Read as proxy' on smart contracts?

Tags: web3.py

Normally I just do this on python:

```
token = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)
balance_in_wei = token.functions.balanceOf(wallet).call()
```

However, when the function isn't in the "Read Contract" tab, this code wouldn't work at all.
[image]

The balanceOf function can be found in "Read as Proxy".
[image]

*How could I call this function as proxy in web3 py?* For context, I'm trying to get my balance of USDC: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found your question in searching for the same issue and struggling for hours. For clear definitions the proxy contract A will point to contract B. What fixed it for me was using the ABI of the contract B and the address of contract A. Best of luck!

Comment: Indeed, in the case where Proxy Contracts are used you need to give Proxy Contract's ABI to initialize web3.Contract object to call functions from. This sould be the accepted answer.

Comment: saved me many hours. thank you

Answer (score 4):

same exact way.  Just pretend it's there and it should work.  Instantiate the contract with the ABI that you want to call (e.g. the one with balanceOf regardless of it's actually there or not)

Comment: The reason why I asked this is because it doesn't work correctly. I used the `token.functions.balanceOf(wallet).call()` function but it's displaying zero, even though I have 10 on my wallet. This function works for all other tokens.

Comment: what's your abi?

Answer (score 0):

I think `balanceOf` returns a `BigNumber` value that needs to be formatted for display purposes. Are you running a formatting function prior to displaying the balance? Formatting functions take a `decimals` argument. Standard ERC-20 tokens implement 18 decimals *but* the USDC contract only implements 6 decimals. So the formatter function args might need to be adjusted.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc20#a-note-on-decimals
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-formatUnits

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the address of main contract and ABi of proxy contract to use main functions of these kind of smart contracts