# How to get totalSupply of USDC using solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, usdc

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

//  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

interface IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
        external
        returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
     * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
     * zero by default.
     *
     * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
     * another (`to`).
     *
     * Note that `value` may be zero.
     */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed spender,
        uint256 value
    );
}

contract Test{
     IERC20 public tokenAddress;
    constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
        // USDc = USDC(0x2058A9D7613eEE744279e3856Ef0eAda5FCbaA7e);
       
         tokenAddress = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    }

   function checkSupply() payable public returns(uint){
        
        return tokenAddress.totalSupply();
        

        
   }
}
```

Comment: This one is correct way. I think the  return should be `returns(uint256)`

Comment: Getting this error- {
 "error": "Failed to decode output: Error: hex data is odd-length (argument=\"value\", value=\"0x0\", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.5.0)"
}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I did not see it properly before. The function you have `checkSupply` should be view function and not payable. Eg.

```
function checkSupply() external view returns(uint256){
    return tokenAddress.totalSupply(); 
 }
```

Comment: Then I am getting this error- The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read from the totalSupply function from the proxy contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#readProxyContract

[image: USDC Etherescan]
[image: Total supply]

Comment: How to get totalSUpply using solidity?

Comment: Check out this question, along with my answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/121370/how-do-i-call-functions-from-read-as-proxy-on-smart-contracts

Comment: I don't want to use web3 or etherjs library, how to get the totalSupply using solidity?